# Regular expression for referrer redirection

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I need the regular expression to redirect a link like this:

```
www.mysite.com/forums/users/tom
```

To: `http://www.mysite.com/dashboard/listings/tom`

The problem is that the script I am using constructs links like this:

```
www.mysite.com/forums/users/tom/favorites/
```

And I need to redirect ONLY the `www.mysite.com/forums/users/tom` and NOT the `www.mysite.com/forums/users/tom/favorites/` which I would like to leave as it is.

Is there any way to do this?

Please help me. :(

Answer (score 0):

This should work and only redirect `mysite.com/referrer/` and not `mysite.com/referrer/topic`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^referrer/$ http://someurl.com [L,R=301]
```

EDIT:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^forums/users/(.*)/?$ http://www.mysite.com/dashboard/listings/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you my friend but this is the problem. The referrer is not static. :(

Comment: But each referrer will be redirected to the same someurl?

Comment: No realize that I have messed it up big time. If you manage to help me on this I may even pay you. Just give me your paypal email and Ill send you $10  :(

Comment: What you said there is different to the url you wanted changed above. Can you edit your question with the links that you want redirected?

Comment: I am very sorry for the trouble. I will send you a payment of $10 in your paypal address if you find me a solution for this. I've edited the post.

Comment: Ive also tried this but I get an internal server error: RewriteRule ^forums\users\(.*)/$ http://www.cashlinkz.com/dashboard/listings/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: In your question you have `www.mysite.com/user/` to go to `www.mysite.com/dir/user`, but you last comment wants it `www.mysite.com/forums/users/` to `www.mysite.com/dashboard/listings/` which is it?

Comment: Try my edit it will send `www.mysite.com/forums/users/tom` to `www.mysite.com/dashboard/listings/tom`.`

Comment: Well is the second. I am sorry but I guessed that its the same but it is not. I never messed with regular expressions again. Ill edit the post again and the payment offer is still valid because Ive lost the whole day today trying to figure out this and it will be a great help for me if you can find me a solution.

Comment: Now the problem got much bigger. I cant get into the admin area even though Ive removed the code you provided from the .htaccess. How can this be possible? :(

Comment: Try it on another browser/clear the cache. Its probably cached in your browser